# Get values from hashmap in Eclipse

Tags: java, hashmap

I am adding to a project done in Eclipse that displays data pulled from various databases to a webpage.  I am trying to figure out how to use a hashmap.  I have a variable/column called "description" that will show a description based on the value of the column just before it.  The descriptions are in my hashmap.  I just don't know how to pull the "description" value.

Here is part of the DtoBuilder -

```
private HashMap<String,String> itemDescrMap = null;

public VersionsDto build(Versions oneVersion){

    VersionsDto result = null;
    if(itemDescrMap==null){
        itemDescrMap = loadItemDescrMap();
    }

    // Create instance of versions object and build it.
    if(oneVersion != null){
        result = new VersionsDto();
        result.setStore(oneVersion.getStore());
        result.setUpdatePackage(oneVersion.getUpdatePackage());
        result.setDescription(oneVersion.getDescription());
```

and here is part of the hashmap -

```
private static HashMap<String,String> loadItemDescrMap(){
    HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();

    map.put("CDSA", "Color Match");
    map.put("CDSB", "New Formula Book");
    map.put("CDSC", "Base Assignments");
    map.put("CDSD", "Product Formulation");
    map.put("CDSE", "Old TAC");
    map.put("CDSF", "Colorant Systems");
    map.put("CDSG", "Miscellaneous");
    map.put("CDSH", "AFCD");
```

Initially, I was just grabbing the same data for "description" as I was for "updatePackage", just to test that it would populate all the fields and display it to the webpage.  So now I need to know how to set the "description" value based on the hash map, where the first values (CDSD, CDSE, etc) are all the possible values in the "updatePackage" column and the second value is the corresponding "description" that I need.

Comment: `itemDescrMap.get(oneVersion.getDescription())` ?

Comment: How does that work with the corresponding `result.setUpdatePackage(oneVersion.getUpdatePackage());` just before it?

Comment: That won't retrieve the correct value you need.  Refer to answer provided by @user6106573

Comment: I hadn't seen that the `itemDescrMap` was actually mapping `UpdatePackages` descriptions (that's badly named as far as I can tell). Then use `itemDescrMap.get(oneVersion.getUpdatePackage())` obviously

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the javadoc https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

I think `itemDescrMap.get(oneVersion.getUpdatePackage())` should do the job

Comment: Does `itemDescrMap.get(oneVersion.getUpdatePackage())` go in place of `result.setDescription(oneVersion.getDescription());` ?

Comment: Your question was " I just don't know how to PULL the "description" value." for which I gave you the answer.
I guess your method setDescription(String) is to PUT "the description" value that you now know how to pull from an hashMap.
Combining these gives (if I understand what you want), result.setDescription(oneVersion.getDescription()); should be replaced by result.setDescription(itemDescrMap.get(oneVersion.getUpdatePackage()));
Make you sure about what you want to do and read the javadoc, you should find and understand the solution.

Comment: I had wondered if `result.setDescription(itemDescrMap.get(oneVersion.getUpdateP‌​ackage()));` might work - didn't know if they could be combined like that (I'm very new to Java).  Had tried finding something like this all yesterday afternoon online and had no luck.  I will attempt and see if it returns what I need.